# How can I export my AAB from Firebase app distribution to Play store?

Tags: android, google-play, firebase-app-distribution

According to [this support article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038):

> When you upload an app bundle to App Distribution, it’s exported to Google Play to generate an APK that's optimized for your tester's device configuration.

But [this answer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/troubleshooting?platform=android#aabs-in-google-play) in Firebase documentation:

> AAB builds you upload to App Distribution do not appear in your Google Play developer account (this includes App Bundle Explorer and internal app sharing).

I would like the AABs uploaded to Firebase by my CI to be available in the Play Store, but they're not. Which article is correct? Is it possible to make it work? I would prefer to not use Fastlane.

Comment: Why do you want to upload the aab to firebase? you can directly upload the file to playstore from your CI/CD. If you have any special case, can you edit your answer with "why you are using the firebase as a middle man"?

Answer (score 0):

Both articles are correct - Firebase needs to **export** the .aab to Google Play so they can generate the SDK. That doesn't mean you will be able to **see** the exported .aab in your Google Play Developer account or the console.

You need to upload the .aab to the Google Play Console yourself as a different operation, either by including that in your CI or uploading the .aab manually